# Different behavior between re.finditer and re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following code:

```
CARRIS_REGEX=r'<th>(\d+)</th><th>([\s\w\.\-]+)</th><th>(\d+:\d+)</th><th>(\d+m)</th>'
pattern = re.compile(CARRIS_REGEX, re.UNICODE)
matches = pattern.finditer(mailbody)
findall = pattern.findall(mailbody)
```

But finditer and findall are finding different things. Findall indeed finds all the matches in the given string. But finditer only finds the first one, returning an iterator with only one element.

How can I make finditer and findall behave the same way?

Thanks

Comment: How are you using the iterator, or determining how many results it will return?

Comment: using a for match in matches and printing them. thanks.

Comment: Can you post a mail body you are having this issue with?

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/8YY8gGGT

Comment: @simao: no repro `list(pattern.finditer(mailbody))` returns a list with 8 elements, the same as with `findall`

Comment: I get same results as SilentGhost - of course, you have to change the finditer call to `list(pattern.finditer(mailbody))`, to unroll the iterator elements into a list.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I can't reproduce this here. Have tried it with both Python 2.7 and 3.1.

One difference between `finditer` and `findall` is that the former returns regex match objects whereas the other returns a tuple of the matched capturing groups (or the entire match if there are no capturing groups).

So

```
import re
CARRIS_REGEX=r'<th>(\d+)</th><th>([\s\w\.\-]+)</th><th>(\d+:\d+)</th><th>(\d+m)</th>'
pattern = re.compile(CARRIS_REGEX, re.UNICODE)
mailbody = open("test.txt").read()
for match in pattern.finditer(mailbody):
    print(match)
print()
for match in pattern.findall(mailbody):
    print(match)
```

prints

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00A63758>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00A63F98>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00A63758>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00A63F98>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00A63758>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00A63F98>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00A63758>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00A63F98>

('790', 'PR. REAL', '21:06', '04m')
('758', 'PORTAS BENFICA', '21:10', '09m')
('790', 'PR. REAL', '21:14', '13m')
('758', 'PORTAS BENFICA', '21:21', '19m')
('790', 'PR. REAL', '21:29', '28m')
('758', 'PORTAS BENFICA', '21:38', '36m')
('758', 'SETE RIOS', '21:49', '47m')
('758', 'SETE RIOS', '22:09', '68m')
```

If you want the same output from `finditer` as you're getting from `findall`, you need

```
for match in pattern.finditer(mailbody):
    print(tuple(match.groups()))
```

Comment: I don't know why it wasn't working. I uninstalled python 2.5 and upgraded to 2.6 and it's working now :|

Answer (score 7):

> **re.findall(pattern.string)**
>
> findall() returns all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string
>   ***as a list of  strings.***
>
> **re.finditer()**
>
> finditer() returns ***callable object***.
>
> In both functions, the string is scanned from left to right and
>   matches are returned in order found.

Answer (score 7):

I get this example from [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) in [Python 2.* Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html) and that example well described here in details with some modification. To explain whole example, let's get string type variable call,

```
text = "He was carefully disguised but captured quickly by police."
```

and the [compile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) type regular expression pattern as,

```
regEX = r"\w+ly"
pattern = re.compile(regEX)
```

`\w` mean *matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore)*, `+` mean *matches 1 or more of the preceding token* and the whole meaning is *select any word which is end-up with* `ly`. There are only two 2 words('carefully' and 'quickly') which is satisfied the above regular expression.

Before move into [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) or [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer), let's see what does [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) mean in [Python 2.* Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html).

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Following code lines gives you the basic understand of [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

```
search = pattern.search(text)
print(search)
print(type(search))

#output
<re.Match object; span=(7, 16), match='carefully'>
<class 're.Match'>
```

It will generate [re.MatchObject](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) of class type object which have 13 of supported methods and attributes according to [Python 2.* Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html). This [span()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.span) method consist with the start and end points(7 and 16 present in the above example) of the matched word in `text` variable. [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) method only consider about the very first match, otherwise return `None`.

Let's move into the question, before that see what does [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) mean in [Python 2.* Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html).

> Return an iterator yielding MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result.

Coming next code lines gives you the basic understand of [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer).

```
finditer = pattern.finditer(text)
print(finditer)
print(type(finditer))

#output
<callable_iterator object at 0x040BB690>
<class 'callable_iterator'>
```

The above example gives us the [Iterator Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/iterator.html#iterator-objects) which need to be loop. This is obviously not the result we want. Let's loop `finditer` and see what's inside this [Iterator Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/iterator.html#iterator-objects).

```
for anObject in finditer:
    print(anObject)
    print(type(anObject))
    print()

#output
<re.Match object; span=(7, 16), match='carefully'>
<class 're.Match'>

<re.Match object; span=(40, 47), match='quickly'>
<class 're.Match'>
```

This results are much similar to the [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) result which we get earlier. But we can see the new result in above output, `<re.Match object; span=(40, 47), match='quickly'>`. As I mention earlier in [Python 2.* Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html), [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) will *scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match* and [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) will *scan through string looking for all the locations where the regular expression pattern produces matches* and return more details than [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) method.

Here what does [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) mean in [Python 2.* Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html).

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

Let's understand what happen in [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

```
findall = pattern.findall(text)
print(findall)
print(type(findall))

#output
['carefully', 'quickly']
<class 'list'>
```

This output only gives us the matched words in `text` variable, otherwise return an empty [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). That [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) in the output which is similar to the `match` attribute in [re.MatchObject](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject).

Here is the full code and I tried in [Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/).

```
import re

text = "He was carefully disguised but captured quickly by police."

regEX = r"\w+ly"
pattern = re.compile(regEX)

search = pattern.search(text)
print(search)
print(type(search))
print()

findall = pattern.findall(text)
print(findall)
print(type(findall))
print()

finditer = pattern.finditer(text)
print(finditer)
print(type(finditer))
print()
for anObject in finditer:
    print(anObject)
    print(type(anObject))
    print()
```

Comment: Very nice and well described  @Kushan

Answer (score 6):

You can't make them behave the same way, because they're different. If you really want to create a list of results from `finditer`, then you could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [match for match in pattern.finditer(mailbody)]
[...]
```

In general, use a `for` loop to access the matches returned by `re.finditer`:

```
>>> for match in pattern.finditer(mailbody):
...     ...
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. Problem is, they don't find the same matches. findall finds all the matches in the string. finditer only finds the first one and yes I used a for in loop to traverse all the elements in the iterator.

Comment: `[match for match in pattern.finditer(mailbody)]` is just a slower and less readable way of saying `list(pattern.finditer(mailbody))`

Answer (score 0):

I came here trying to get a string from my `.finditer()`'s regex results

The solution was practically that I needed to create *at least one group*, which enabled fetching it from the group dict

```
-     yield from zip(re.finditer(r"\w+", line) ...
+     yield from zip(re.finditer(r"(\w+)", line) ...
...
-     block.(miscellaneous attempts)
+     block.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of  finditer() when you are extracting from a large file since it will return an iterator object which helps in saving memory on the other hand findall() returns a list. And finditer() will extract differently than findall().

For example:

```
    text_to_search = '''
    abcdefghijklmnopqurtuvwxyz
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\s
    321-555-4321
    1234567890
    Ha HaHa
    MetaCharacters (Need to be escaped):
    . ^ $ * + ? { } [ ] \ | ( )
    khanafsaan11.com
    321-555-4321
    123.555.1234
    123*555*-1234
    123.555.1234
    800-555-1234
    900-555-1234
    Mr. Schafer
    Mr Smith
    Ms Davis
    Mrs. Robinson
    Mr. T
    Mr_hello
    '''
    pattern=re.compile(r'M(r|rs|s)\.? [A-Z][a-z]*')
    print(list(pattern.finditer(text_to_search))) #converted to list
    print(pattern.findall(text_to_search))
```

Output:

```
    ['r', 'r', 's', 'rs', 'r'] 
    [, , , , ]
```

And you can get the output like findall() from finditer() output as following

```
    for obj in pattern.finditer(text_to_search):
        print(obj.group()) #group() is an attribute of re.Match object
    #ouput
    Mr. Schafer
    Mr Smith
    Ms Davis
    Mrs. Robinson
    Mr. T
```

Answer (score 0):

finditer() returns iterator object, finditer() helps with memory efficency its based on the generators.

def my_ranger(max_num):