# Converting C++ Boost Regexes to Python re regexes

Tags: python, c++, regex, boost

The aim is to convert these regexes in `C++` `boost` to `Python` `re` regexes:

```
  typedef boost::u32regex tRegex;

  tRegex emptyre = boost::make_u32regex("^$");
  tRegex commentre = boost::make_u32regex("^;.*$");
  tRegex versionre = boost::make_u32regex("^@\\$Date: (.*) \\$$");
  tRegex includere = boost::make_u32regex("^<(\\S+)$");
  tRegex rungroupre = boost::make_u32regex("^>(\\d+)$");
  tRegex readreppre = boost::make_u32regex("^>(\\S+)$");
  tRegex tokre = boost::make_u32regex("^:(.*)$");
  tRegex groupstartre = boost::make_u32regex("^#(\\d+)$");
  tRegex groupendre = boost::make_u32regex("^#$");
  tRegex rulere = boost::make_u32regex("^([!-+^])([^\\t]+)\\t+([^\\t]*)$");
```

I could rewrite these regexes one by one but there're quite a lot more that the example above, so my question is with regards to

- **how to convert C++ boost regexest to Python** and
- **what is the difference between boost regexes and python re regexes?**

**Is the C++ `boost::u32regex` the same as `re` regexes in python?** If not, what is the difference? (Links to the docs would be much appreciated =) ) For instance:

- in boost, there's `boost::u32regex_match`, is that the same as 
  `re.match`?
- in boost, there's `boost::u32regex_search`, how is it different to `re.search`
- there's also `boost::format_perl` and `boost::match_default` and `boost::smatch`, what are their equivalence in `python` `re`?

Comment: Note that `[!-+]` matches `!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, and `+` (`rulere` regex). All the regexps here will work the same in Python. If you have more complex patterns, please share. `re.match` is not the same as `regex_match` as `re.match` is looking for the match at the beginning of the string, and `regex_match` requires a full string match. `regex_search` behaves as `regex_search`. You can add a `$` anchor to the patterns that are used with `regex_match` and pass them to `re.match`. There are no `boost::format_perl` and `boost::match_default` flags. Smatch is `finditer`.

Comment: It's actually from this `.cpp` code: https://gist.github.com/alvations/99354d0fbe294c14cf7f that is used to read a series of `.rpp` files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppgglwvwz16hlt1/erg.zip?dl=0 from this software http://moin.delph-in.net/ReppTop. We're trying to port this python.

Comment: My suggestion is that don't try to make this work in Python `re`. Use `regex` package instead. In the gist, I see the input being interpreted as regex. The user-inputted regex may use advanced features in Boost, which might not be available in Python re. Also, if you are dealing with Unicode, you should use Python 3.3+. As for the rest of the question, it's too broad.

Comment: *`regex_search` behaves as `regex_search`* should have been *`regex_search` behaves as `re.search`*. I agree with nhahtdh that the question is broad and since you have not shared all regexps you have it is also unclear (no idea how complex they all are and if they can be ported to Python as is). A rule of thumb is not to blindly use one language code in another.

Comment: @stribizhev, the zip file from the dropbox link contains all the regexes that is supposed to be read. They are in LISP format, so the C++ regex in the questions are used to read the LISP regexes.

Comment: What is your anticipated encoding? u32regex (icu.hpp) convert both the _regex_ input as well as the _subject_ string to Utf-32. Kind of homogenous.

Comment: The anticipated encoding ranges from utf8 to utf32.

Comment: For boost Unicode (ICU) regex. the only reason to use make_u32regex is to use the ICU property libraries. In that case, all roads lead to utf-32, no matter what the input regex and subject encoding's are utf8/16/32. With macro languages, the default Unicode internal encoding is usually utf-8, and they provide their own versions of Unicode properties. So, none of these should be an issue. The only thing that _could_ be an issue would be to convert any special boost constructs to a standardized form. This may mean collating elements or others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **How to convert C++ boost regexest to Python**

In case of a simple regex, like `\w+\s+\d+`, or `>.*$` you won't have to change the pattern. In case of more complex patterns with constructs mentioned below, you will most probably have to re-write a regex. As with any conversion from one flavor/language to another, the general answer is **DON'T**. However, Python and Boost do have some similarities, especially when it comes to simple patterns (if Boost is using PCRE-like pattern) containing a dot (`a.*b`), regular (`[\w-]*`) and negated (`[^>]*`) character classes, regular quantifiers like `+`/`*`/`?`, and suchlike.

> **what is the difference between boost regexes and python `re` regexes?**

**[Python `re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re)** is not that rich as **[Boost regexps](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)** (suffice is to mention such constructs as [`\h`, `\G`, `\K`, `\R`, `\X`, `\Q...\E`, branch reset, recursion, possessive quantifiers, POSIX character classes and character properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), [extended replacement pattern](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html)), and other features that Boost has. The `(?imsx-imsx:pattern)` is limited to the whole expression in Python, not to a part of it thus you should be aware that `(?i)` in your `&amp;|&#((?i)x26);|&#38;` will be treated as if it were at the beginning of the pattern (however, it does not have any impact on this expression).

Also, same as in Boost, you do not have to escape `[` inside a character class, and `{` outside the character class.

The backreferences  like `\1` are the same as in Python.

Since you are not using capturing groups in alternation in your patterns (e.g. `re.sub(r'\d(\w)|(go\w*)', '\2', 'goon')`), there should be no problem (in such cases, Python does not fill in the non-participating group with any value, and returns an empty result).

Note the difference in named group definition: `(?<NAME>expression)`/`(?'NAME'expression)` in Boost, and `(?P<NAME>expression)` in Python.

I see your regexps mainly fall under "simple" category. The most complex pattern is a [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (e.g. `⌊-((?:(?!-⌋).)*)-⌋`). To optimize them, you could use an *[unroll the loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)* technique, but it may not be necessary depending on the size of texts you handle with the expressions.

The most troublesome part as I see it is that you are using Unicode literals heavily. In Python 2.x, all strings are byte arrays, and you will always have to make sure you pass a unicode object to the Unicode regexps (see [*Python 2.x’s Unicode Support*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support)). In Python 3, all strings are UTF8 by default, and you can even use UTF8 literal characters in source code without any additional actions (see [*Python’s Unicode Support*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support)). So, Python 3.3+ (with support for raw string literals) is a good candidate.

Now, as for the remaining questions:

> in boost, there's `boost::u32regex_match`, is that the same as  `re.match`?

The **[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)** is not the same as regex_match as `re.match` is looking for the match ***at the beginning of the string***, and [`regex_match`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html) requires ***a full string match***. However, in Python 3, you can use **[`re.fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch)** that is equivalent to Boost `regex_match`.

> in boost, there's `boost::u32regex_search`, how is it different to `re.search`

Whenver you need to find a match anywhere inside a string, you need to use `re.search` (see [*`match()` versus `search()`*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#match-versus-search)). Thus, this method provides analoguous functionality as [`regex_search`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) does in Boost.

> there's also `boost::format_perl` and `boost::match_default` and `boost::smatch`, what are their equivalence in python `re`?

Python does not support Perl-like expressions to the extent Boost can, Python `re` module is just a "trimmed" Perl regex engine that does not have many nice features I mentioned earlier. Thus, no flags like `default` or `perl` can be found there. As for the `smatch`, you can use **[`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer)** to get all the [match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). A [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns all matches (or submatches only if capturing groups are specified) as a list of strings/lists of tuples. See the [`re.findall`/`re.finditer` difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765024/different-behavior-between-re-finditer-and-re-findall).

And in the conclusion, a must-read article [*Python’s re Module*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/python.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!!! I'm still digesting the information after reading =)